# AWS - EBS Snapshots is exceeding free tier

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

2 months ago I started using AWS and now I am having an issue with the Free Tier.

I installed a system with the elastic beanstalk tool (1 EC2 and 1 RDS).

Now I am seeing in Management Dashboard that I will be exceeding my monthly limit for EBS Snapshots. The forecast is 194.94% and I am just starting the month.

I reviewed all the settings and I couldn't find anything strange.

EC2

```
1 Running instances
1 volumes
2 Key Pairs
1 Elastic Ips
1 Snapshots
```

By looking the volume menu in AWS, the Snapshot id in the only volume that I have is not the same as the snapshot that I have. This is strange.

volume information:

```
Volume ID   --> vol-0cff610c
Size        --> 8 Gib
Volume type --> gp2
IOPS        --> 100 / 3000
Snapshot    --> snap-04786
State       --> in-use
```

And in the snapshot menu, the volume id is not the same as the volume that I have in the other view.

Snapshot Information

```
Snapshot ID --> snap-0d2988
Size        --> 8Gib
Volume      --> vol-05f5fee
Status      --> completed
```

Does anybody have an idea of what is causing this problem with the EBS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

today I reviewed again the information and AWS console.

My problem was that I have an unused AMI and the snapshot was related to that AMI.

I thought that the only AMI I had was being used by the instance. But I was wrong, the AMI used in the instance was a different one. Probably because I started my instance with elastic beanstalk.

So the solution was to deregister this unused AMI, then delete the Snapshot.

Thanks to all

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, **don't panic**. EBS Snapshots are 5c/GB/month. Worst case, 8GB = 40c/month.

Secondly, if you don't want a snapshot, **just delete it**. Especially if you don't remember making it, and don't need to keep it.

Comment: I think OP is also confused about the snapshot-id on a volume, which is the snapshot the volume is created *from*.  OP also needs to check other regions.

Comment: Thanks John, I tried to delete the snapshot, but I cant since is related to an AMI. 

If I am not wrong, the AMI is used to start the EC2 instance, right?. (I only have 1)

Michael, I already checked all other regions in order to be sure that I don't have anything else running.

Comment: Ah! sqlbot might be right. You are only charged for Snapshots shown in the **Snapshots** section of the console. Don't worry about other snapshot IDs you see — they are simply used to create the default AMIs and belong to AWS (no charge).

Answer (score 0):

Elastic Beanstalk can create AWS resources and terminate them automatically for you, depending on your workload.

If your server was under heavy workload at some point, Elastic Beanstalk could have provisioned auto scaling group with Elastic Load Balancer, and the number of EC2 instances can increase to cater for the increased workload.

As the workload drops, it can terminate the instances for you as well. Resulting in left-over snapshots, especially if you code writes to the local EC2 hdd.

Elastic Beanstalk is the "one-click" solution for deploying scalable clusters of servers.

Similar services are as follow :

1. Elastic Beanstalk (easiest)
2. OpsWorks
3. Cloud Formation (hardest)

LightSail is not included here as it doesn't really scale automatically. Lambda is serverless so it is fundamentally different.

Comment: Thanks Gapton, last month I had 2 instances running at some point, then I fixed the issue and continued using 1. But now I have only minimum settings, and I am worried because I dont understand why I am "using more EBS". Thanks!